# Regular expression - extract 6 digits exactly

Tags: c#, regex

Yoav - edited to be clearer

Hi,
I need to find 6 digit numerical strings in a text file. I'm working in C#.
Example:

```
text text text123365 text text text
```

The expression must skip strings longer then 6:

```
text text text1233656 text text text
```

The above string should not return any result because the length of the digit string is 7.

I came up with this expression: `[^0-9]([0-9]){6}[^0-9]`

It works perfectly with the exception of string that are at the start or end of the line

```
123365text text text text text text
text text text text text text123365
```

Is it possible to identify these cases?

Comment: note that the quantifier should be placed within the capture brackets, as in `([0-9]{6})`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try:

```
(?<!\d)\d{6}(?!\d)
```

It says:

- Find 6 digits that are not directly preceeded or succeeded with a digit

It will look anywhere in the string.

Examples:

> 123365text text text text text text
>   text text text text text text123365

Matches:

1. 123365
2. 123365

> 123365text text text 234098 text text text
>   text text text text text 567890 text123365

Matches:

1. 123365
2. 234098
3. 567890
4. 123365

Comment: I think Yoav specifically want to match cases where there is no word boundary separating the digits from the letters - e.g test123456 or 654321test. Your regex won't match these cases.

Comment: "The expression must skip strings longer then 6:

text text text1233656 text text text

The above string should not return any result". From that quote I thought he did NOT want to match numbers attached to other strings. Oh well. The question is a bit vague.

Comment: Well, there MAY be a word boundary but there SHOULD not necessarily be. Note that [^0-9] also matches a white space character.

Comment: @PatrikAkerstrand, as to your comment, the reason is that there are actually 7 digits in that string.

Comment: I know, I saw that just now, when people started to downvote. Nevertheless the question is a bit vague on that point. I'll update the answer.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. Note that the string where I did not want a match has a 7 digit string. I will edit my question to make it clearer for anyone else who stumbles upon it.

Answer (score 6):

```
System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex re = 
    new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(@"(^|\D)(\d{6})($|\D)");
```

Comment: +1 this is probably the correct answer, matching start of string OR non-digit, then 6 digits, then end of string OR non-digit. Unfortunately your regex cannot be seen at glance because the code block needs to be scrolled.

Comment: Don't use \d unless you know what you are doing. It includes non-ASCII digits, like BENGALI DIGIT ZERO ০

Comment: @xanatos That's a rather vague blanket statement. I can see cases where you would want to do the exact opposite. Use \d *because* you don't know what you're doing. If you want any digit, you're likely to forget about those other digits that aren't within the normal ASCII range, but \d will remember.

Comment: @BlueMonkMN Can you be sure the OP, who didn't know how to make a quite easy Regex, knows how \d works, and that it works differently in JS, or the fact that nearly all the conversion methods string->number of C# accept only [0-9]?

Comment: @xanatos It doesn't matter whether the OP knows how \d works. What matters is whether \d gets what the OP wants. Can you be sure the OP doesn't want some characters that are defined as digits when he says he wants "digits"?  A better statement than "Don't use \d" would be "Be careful using \d because some digits that it includes are non-ASCII values and cannot be converted to numbers with most numeric parsers."  The fact that the OP wants exactly 6 digits suggests that this piece of text may not be getting converted to an integer.

Answer (score 5):

I think you'd be better off using negative lookahead and lookbehind to do this rather than boundaries or not matches, like:

```
(?<![0-9])[0-9]{6}(?![0-9])
```

Comment: I added some brackets you have forgotten. +1 for lookaround, would have been my choice, too (although I would have dropped the capturing parentheses).

Comment: Thanks Tim! Noticed that myself just after posting... Edited

Answer (score 0):

I was about to suggest the same thing as [PatrikAkerstrand](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5326188/regular-expression-extract-6-digits-exactly/5326246#5326246) (`\b\d{6}\b`). Instead, I'll post a link to [a working example on Rubular](http://rubular.com/r/z2dPI4KUJk).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
(^|[^0-9])(?<num>[0-9]{6})[^0-9]
```

This appears to match as you want. I tested it out using [Regexdesigner](http://www.sellsbrothers.com/Posts/Details/12425)

Answer (score -1):

We needed to match 6 digits, anywhere in a string (single line). This variation of the above is what ended up working for us:

```
(^|\b)(\d{6})(\b|$)
```

Comment: This is the same as [Dan Tao's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5326188/regular-expression-extract-6-digits-exactly/5326271#5326271); the anchors are redundant.  And it doesn't meet the OP's requirements because it won't match the digits in string like `123456test` or `test123456`.

Comment: To late with edit, you already said that. Blame lack of sleep ... How about this?: (^|\b|\B)(\d{6})(\b|$)

Comment: `\b` is never going to be useful for this particular problem.  I think the regex in the accepted answer, `(?<!\d)\d{6}(?!\d)`, is the only reasonable way to do this.