# How to check float values in excel using regular expression?

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

Using following code I can easily identify single character in a cell. But I have to make sure that not only character but it can detect word and symbols (except "."). 
In other words I have to make sure that cell contain only float values like 4.1, 12.14,12345.2154,0.1 etc.

```
string pattern = @"^[a-zA-Z]$";
int rowCnt = 0;
if (ExcelDataTable.Rows.Count > 0)
{
foreach (DataRow row in ExcelDataTable.Rows)
{
   rowCnt += 1;
  if (Regex.IsMatch(Convert.ToString(row[5]), pattern))
  {
  }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try this Regex

```
[-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+
```

Comment: thank u so much. can u please explain me that expression it will be a great help..

Comment: + or - followed by Zero or More occurrence of number followed by'.' with again number

Comment: hi akshay. i have made small modification in your regular expression [-+]?([0-9]{0,6})\.?([0-9]{1,6}) so that it accepts 6 digit before and after decimal but it is also accepting following input "123456789123". acceptable values are (123456,123456.123456) Plz help

Comment: you want to accept Number like 123456.123456, 123456, means It Number Should and Only have  6 digits before and after decimal point?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5326188/regular-expression-extract-6-digits-exactly

Comment: Console.WriteLine("Enter number to Validate");
            string s = Console.ReadLine();

            Match match = Regex.Match(s, @"\d{6}.\d{6}",RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
            if (match.Success)
            {
                // Finally, we get the Group value and display it.
                Console.WriteLine("Number Matched");
            }
            Console.ReadLine();